# Spring Batch combine FlatFileItemReader with database reading

Tags: spring-boot, csv, spring-batch, supercsv

My current Spring Boot application runs a scheduler job with Spring Batch configuration where I have a `FlatFileItemReader` for reading the CSV rows, and a simple ItemWriter.

```
FlatFileItemReader<MyCsvRowDto>
ItemWriter<MyCsvRowDto>
```

Based on the chunk setup the CSV rows are red 1-by-1, and the writer gets all the data in a list.

I need to extend this logic to be able to read the rows from CSV and additionally a few things from repositories.

```
ItemReader<MyData>
ItemWriter<MyData>
```

where MyData contains the rows from CSV and additional things from repositories:

```
public class MyData {
  private MyDatabaseData dbData;
  private List<MyCsvRowData> csvData;
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do it still with `FlatFileItemReader` somehow, or I need to write a custom ItemReader where I read the data from repositories and then separately the CSV rows with `supercsv`?

Comment: Use an `ItemProcessor` to enrich your data don't try to shoehorn this into a custom reader.

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said, an item processor is the way to go when items need to be enriched. This is a common pattern described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders.